# Why does the crawler4j example give an error?

Tags: java, crawler4j

I'm trying to use the Basic crawler example in crawler4j. I took the code from the crawler4j website [here](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/basic/).

```
package edu.crawler;

import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.parser.HtmlParseData;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.http.Header;

public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {

    private final static Pattern FILTERS = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g" + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4"
                    + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf" + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

    /**
     * You should implement this function to specify whether the given url
     * should be crawled or not (based on your crawling logic).
     */
    @Override
    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
            String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
            return !FILTERS.matcher(href).matches() && href.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/");
    }

    /**
     * This function is called when a page is fetched and ready to be processed
     * by your program.
     */
    @Override
    public void visit(Page page) {
            int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();
            String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
            String domain = page.getWebURL().getDomain();
            String path = page.getWebURL().getPath();
            String subDomain = page.getWebURL().getSubDomain();
            String parentUrl = page.getWebURL().getParentUrl();
            String anchor = page.getWebURL().getAnchor();

            System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            System.out.println("Domain: '" + domain + "'");
            System.out.println("Sub-domain: '" + subDomain + "'");
            System.out.println("Path: '" + path + "'");
            System.out.println("Parent page: " + parentUrl);
            System.out.println("Anchor text: " + anchor);

            if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
                    HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
                    String text = htmlParseData.getText();
                    String html = htmlParseData.getHtml();
                    List<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls();

                    System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
                    System.out.println("Html length: " + html.length());
                    System.out.println("Number of outgoing links: " + links.size());
            }

            Header[] responseHeaders = page.getFetchResponseHeaders();
            if (responseHeaders != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response headers:");
                    for (Header header : responseHeaders) {
                            System.out.println("\t" + header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue());
                    }
            }

            System.out.println("=============");
    }
}
```

Above is the code for the crawler class from the example.

```
public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String crawlStorageFolder = "../data/";
            int numberOfCrawlers = 7;

            CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
            config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);

            /*
             * Instantiate the controller for this crawl.
             */
            PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
            RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
            RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
            CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

            /*
             * For each crawl, you need to add some seed urls. These are the first
             * URLs that are fetched and then the crawler starts following links
             * which are found in these pages
             */
            controller.addSeed("http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/");
            controller.addSeed("http://www.ics.uci.edu/~lopes/");
            controller.addSeed("http://www.ics.uci.edu/");

            /*
             * Start the crawl. This is a blocking operation, meaning that your code
             * will reach the line after this only when crawling is finished.
             */
            controller.start(MyCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
    }
}
```

Above is the class for the controller class for the web crawler.
When I try to run the Controller class from my IDE (Intellij) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Is there something about the maven config that is found [here](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/wiki/MavenConfig) that I should know? Do I have to use a different version or something?

Comment: From the sounds of it, you're trying to execute a version of the code that was compiled on a later version of Java then the one your are running.  For example.  The code was compiled with Java 7 and your running Java 6 or it was compiled with Java 6 and you are running Java 5...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Comment: @hey j.jerrod taylor..I am facing the issue in the very basic program.i am getting an exception                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
 at com.crawler.web.BasicCrawlController.main(BasicCrawlController.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest  ,Please suggest if any other Jar is also required.

Comment: @AmritpalSingh For me the problem was that I was using a version of the code that was compiled using a different version of Java than the one that I had installed on my computer. If you have the same problem then you should either update your version of Java or use an older version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with crawler4j. The problem was that the version of Java that I was using was different from the latest version of Java that is used in crawler4j. I switched the version right before they updated to Java 7 and everything worked fine. I'm guessing that upgrading my version of Java to 7 would have the same effect.

Comment: shall i crawl dynamic website using crawler4j (java).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264931/crawling-dynamic-website-using-java?noredirect=1#comment43002565_27264931